# Keep Facebook likes private

Tags: facebook-like

My friends say that they are notified when I like a post on Facebook. I don't want this. What is the privacy option that can help me?
Also the are notified when i comment a post on Facebook.

How can i stop this?

Comment: This is an issue of privacy from the other side. When you "like" someone's post that person should see that. Would you want to not be notified when others are "liking" your posts?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your profile (**About**) where your likes are listed. In the section by the title **Likes**, in the top right corner, click the small button and select **Edit privacy**. These settings apply to the visibility of your likes not only in this section but also in the feed.